# create volume in docker and use it in a container

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a application container myapp and a database container sqldb.
I have a sql file in which I want to import my database into my application. But it flushes the data as the container stops.

So for that I want to use volume so that my database remain updated.
I have seen the docs to how to create volume but I m confused.

Please tell me how i will use my updated database using volume?
And how to create volume and link it to my application container?

Answer (score 1):

You have a concrete example using mysql [in this blog post](http://blog.awolski.com/using-docker-to-spin-up-databases-for-development/):

First, it create a [**data volume container**](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/) (a container which never runs, but contains data and is mounted by other container(s))

```
 docker create -v /var/lib/mysql --name my-database mysql  /bin/true
```

Then it runs the database itself, mounting the first data volume container with the `--volumes-from` option:

```
 docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 3306:3306 --volumes-from my-database -d mysql`
```

> I don't have, nor do I want to install, a MySQL client (visual or otherwise) on my pristine laptop.
>   So how are do we get the schema and data into our MySQL container running on Docker? The answer is to run whatever commands we need using another MySQL Docker container linked to our 'server instance'

```
docker run -it --link mysql:mysql --rm mysql sh -c \
   'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" \
   -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot \
   -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" \
   -e "create schema my-schema"'`
```

That commands runs *another* mysql container, except this one is only used to execute a `mysql` command, linked to the mysql container which is running the actual database.

> Check that the database was created:

```
$ docker run -it --link mysql:mysql --rm mysql sh -c \
    'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" \
    -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot \
    -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" \
    -e "show databases"'
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| my-schema          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```